# Why does WebStorm render JSDoc comments' Markdown properly for properties, but not for functions?

Tags: markdown, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm trying to document code in a .ts file. Here are the comments as they are typed:

[image: Typed Comments]

And here they are rendered:

[image: Rendered Comments]

There are other JSDoc markdown issues for functions besides this one. What's interesting is `<br>` still works, but I am still wondering why markdown only works correctly for the properties and not the functions.

I've looked and wasn't able to find any explanation as to why the two comments would be rendered differently, and I wasn't able to find anyone else even talking about the same issue. And there doesn't seem to be any mention of markdown comments at jetbrains.com.

Here they talk about JSDoc but don't mention Markdown or functions and properties rendering differently.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-jsdoc-comments.html

Here they talk about Markdown, but it's for Markdown .md *files*, not JSDoc comments.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/markdown.html

I've also found people complaining about the exact opposite problem, where the comments were being rendered with line breaks for every line break they made in the comments (although I can't find it)

Comment: Please follow [WEB-51929](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51929) and linked tickets for updates